# Java A bit confused with Polymorphic concept in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

Example program:

```
class Animal {
  public void eat() {
    System.out.println(" Animal eats");
  }
  class Dog extends Animal {
    public void eat(String s) {
      System.out.println(" Dog eats" + s);
    }
    public class Demo {
      public static void main(String args[]){
        Animal a = new Dog();
        Dog d = (Dog) a;
        a.eat();         
        d.eat("Meat");
      }
    }
```

My question is why `a.eat("Meat")` is not reachable? Since `a` is Object during the time it's referring to Dog Object, it should allow to call `eat("meat")`.

Can anyone clarify where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please show the exact error, and fix your indentation. It's very hard to read.

Comment: In short: `eat()` is not equal to `eat(String)`.

Comment: Also, System needs to be capitized, and the signature for Dog's eat method is inconsistent with its base class. You aren't actually overriding the base class method. Using the `override` annotation would have shown you that.

Comment: The *variable* `a` is not a `Dog`, even though the *object* that it refers to, is.  If you want to call `Dog` methods using `a` you need to cast it first.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call method of subclass `Dog` through variable of base class `Animal`.

Java has strong typing, so if you declare variable of class `Animal` you can access only to methods and fields of Animal and its superclasses. 
You can call `eat("Meat")` from Animal using casting `((Dog) a).eat("Meat")` but you should avoid as much as possible such constructions.

Btw, your approach looks like a function overloading rather than polymorphism.

P.S. Maybe [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) about strong typing will be helpful for you. And [this one](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/03/polymorphism-in-java/) about difference between overloading and polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

`Dog d = (Dog) a;`

Here you are casting the `Animal a` to a `Dog`. However, this does not change the type of `a`. `a` is still an `Animal` hence you can only call `eat()` without a string.

Comment: Yeah, that's true and make sense